# wordpress thumbnails won't show after import

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have been importing my `wp site` **posts** to another domain and the posts `thumbnails` won't show up.
I would like to correct manually in the database this relationship but I don't really understand the structure.
Is there somebody who could explain the secret of `_thumbnail_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed wp_home and site_url to your new domain? You can either do this via database (found in wp_options) table, or define the values in wp-config.php (found in your wp-installs root) like this:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://newaddress.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://newaddress.com');
```

If this doesn't help, you could use the Wordpress plugin Search and Replace, to replace instances of your old website to your new one.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the old url is embedded within the database, so you could [use this tool](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace:

```
http://your-old-url-exactly-how-it-was/
```

with

```
http://www.your-new-url.com/
```

That would then show up your images, as they are on a different domain?

Comment: Okay it won't help and I dare to suppose because the attachment meta datas are not imported to my database